# Routes with params in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using BrowserRouter and Routes with params [xyz/:id] as shown below. In local host this works fine, but when I deploy in production page cannot open xyz/:id. Kindly help to resolve. 
I do not want to use HashRouter since hash has issue related to security in production.

**Snippet**:

**Index.js**

```
 <Router basename="/my-app">
    <App />
  </Router>,
```

**App.js**

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact={true} path="/xyz/:id" component={MyPage} />
          <Route component={Invalid} />
        </Switch>
```

Comment: Whichever server you are using for deployment, set a redirection for all paths to index.html. That will allow the client side to use the routes

Comment: I think this has more to do with how your server is configured than `react-router` itself, not seeing issues with your router code. I guess you could try explicitly using `<BrowserRouter>` but not sure that'd resolve the issue -  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Router.md

Answer (score 0):

You need to route all requests to your index.html file. For example if you are deploying your app to Apache web server, you can add a .htaccess file to the root of your site and write the following lines of code in it.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```